# REACT rerender on react-video-thumbnail-image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, video, thumbnails

i i use "react-video-thumbnail-image" the video thumbnail is generated on each render of the component. But it only should render one time and not again.

How can i do that?

Comment: A snippet or codesandbox  example would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to control re-rendering.

For class components:

- shouldComponentUpdate (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)
- React.PureComponent (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent)

For functional components:

- React.memo() (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)